# Laravel and HTML Form Builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I like the Form Builder.  Go Laravel.

What's the difference between the [Illuminate version](https://github.com/illuminate/html) and the [Laravel Collective version](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/tree/5.0/src), and which should we use?  Is the Illuminate version now defunct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have an explanation here : http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/upgrade#upgrade-5.0
under **Form & HTML Helpers**

Basically, the Illuminate versions of the Form helper and HTML helper are deprecated in the current version of Laravel and have been removed from the framework's core. They are now maintained by the Laravel Collective.

So if you working with Laravel 5, you should use the Laravel Collective version, you can find it here: [laravel Collective: Forms & HTML](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html)

Comment: Thanks for the ref.  Do you know why Taylor has deprecated this in L5?

Comment: I think it's to keep the framework as minimal and modular as possible. Html and form helpers are more like an extension that you can use if you need to.

Comment: exactly, plus html/form helpers are pretty lame.. just write html, plain and simple, more readable, etc

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 5 it is not standard anymore, but you can add it quickly in the composer file if you prefer to work with forms like you did in Laravel 4.

Just add this line in the composer.json, under the **require** section:

```
"illuminate/html": "5.*"
```

After this step you first need to run the **composer update** command and you should be good to add the rest.

Then you need to add the service providers in config/app.php under **providers** section like this:

```
Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider
```

And as the last part enter these two lines in the config/app.php under **aliases** section:

```
'Form'=> 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',
'HTML'=> 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade'
```